# NestJS Перехват ошибки парсинга Json запроса

Tags: nestjs

Использую NestJS.

Запросы принимает единственный контроллер.

```
import { Controller, Post, Req, Header } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Request } from 'express'
import { RpcService } from './infrastructure/services/rpc/rpc.service'

@Controller()
export class AppController {
    constructor(
        private readonly rpcService: RpcService,
    ) {}

    @Post()
    @Header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    async index(@Req() request: Request): Promise<object> {
        return this.rpcService.call(request.body)
    }
}
```

Если отправляю запрос с невалидным JSON в теле, то получаю вот такой ответ:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Unexpected end of JSON input"
}
```

Подскажите, где и как я могу получить тело запроса раньше этой ошибки, обработать самостоятельно и вернуть клиенту собственный ответ.

Пробовал для этого использовать Middleware и Exception filters. Не получилось, до них доходит дело только, если я отправляю валидный json. В случае с невалидным json до них выполнение не доходит. Проверка осуществляется где-то раньше. Очень хотелось бы узнать где и найти способ эту проверку перехватить.

Comment: попробуй убрать декоратор `@Header`

Comment: пробовал, ничего не поменялось.

Comment: То есть не происходит вызов функции индекс? Что-то я сомневаюсь.

Comment: брэйкпойнт внутрь функции ставлю, но выполнение не останавливается, в ответ на запрос получаю ошибку. Получается json парсится где то раньше, удивительно конечно.

Comment: Через IDE или с помощью `debugger`?  Надежнее просто консоль лог.

Comment: Через IDE. Консоль лог естесственно не срабатывает тоже.

Comment: мб сам браузер блокирует? как вариант там и там поменять `Content-Type` на текст

Comment: Через постман запрос отправляю.
Но мне не надо текст я хочу именно application/json

Comment: Ваш код вызывает больше вопросов. Во первых совершенно не понятно что вы реализуете в файле `rpc.service.ts`, во вторых совершенно не понятно по какой причине вы используете `.call()` метод, в котором вы передаете `body` в качестве контекста, это можно было решить и без вызова `.call()`. В третьих я не уверен что Nest понимает что в качестве результата отдает `Promise<object>`.

Comment: Call вызывает нужный метод описанный в body, и возвращает промис. Но это не так важно, потому что в случае с невалидным json до вызова call дело не доходит, ошибка вываливается раньше. Я хочу ее отловить.